# Post messages to users wall from external application in php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post messages to users wall from my admin side. I have collection of users details with fb id in db, that who liked my app. From admin side I need to post messages to users wall, no spam, it will be monthly. Now I could do something that sending with my login, but when I checked with another user login (who hasn't the app creator), its not working.

*******EDIT******************
When I send from my ID, am created the app, its sending. The problem is sending some other id.
Actually its normal web page I am just authenticating using Facebook

Some cases I am getting this error (#1) An error occured while creating the share

Please see my code

```
$access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();          
            $args = array(
                'message'   => $this->input->post('message'),
                'link'      => 'http://www.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'caption'   => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'description' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'access_token' => $access_token,
            );

            try {
                //will be user id,to this id  i am sending message 
                $this->facebook->api("/".$user_details[0]->fb_id."/feed/",'post', $args);
                $feedbackMessage = "Your message successfully posted to users wall";    
            }
            catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

                $feedbackMessage = "Something went wrong";
                print_r($e->getMessage());


            }
```

Comment: You'll have to use an application access token in order to be able to do this.

Comment: I am getting the application access token like AAAEmbk4MWy8**********. Can u specific more? If u can provide some code would be better, I am new to fb app

Comment: Well can you tell us what exactly you mean by "its not working"? Are you getting an error of some kind?

Comment: What output do you get when it fails? It should give you an error with an error number.